# how to get specific day with javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to get specific day when user inputs a specific date in the form, but the output is not as expected. I have tried some code in mind but not work, could you tell me what is wrong by reviewing this code:

```
<code>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> The day of your birthday</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<p> day :</p>
<input type="text" id="day"/>
<p> month :</p>
<input type="text" id="month"/>
<p> year :</p>
<input type="text" id="year"/><br/>


<input type="button" value="Check "onclick="dayBirthDay()"/>
<input type="reset" value="reset">
</form>
<p id="ok"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">

function dayBirthDay(){
    var t = new Date();
    var day = document.getElementById('day').value;
    var month = document.getElementById('month').value;
    var year = document.getElementById('year').value
    t.setDate(day);
    t.setMonth(month);
    t.setYear(year);
 // how to fix this?? i've try using monthDay. but both is don't seem logic
    var weekDay = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday",     "Friday", "Saturday"]
    document.getElementById('ok').innerHTML = "you were born at " +    weekDay[t.getDay()];
}
    console.log(Date());


    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
</code>
```

Comment: What *exactly* are you seeing go wrong? What are you seeing compared with what you expected? Have you examined the `Date` to see whether that's correct? (I'd probably set year, then month, then day, but I don't know whether that's the issue...)

Comment: What does it return, instead? Wrong value or nothing? Any errors in a console?

Comment: What is expected result of `weekDay[t.getDay()]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can see wrong with it is that month's in JS Date() is 0 based, so subtract your given month by 1:

`t.setMonth(month-1);`

Comment: You were right thanks :) i dont know we can set it to month-1

Answer (score 0):

Your code does work:

```js
function dayBirthDay(){
    var t = new Date();
    var day = document.getElementById('day').value;
    var month = document.getElementById('month').value;
    var year = document.getElementById('year').value
    t.setDate(day);
    t.setMonth(month);
    t.setYear(year);
 
    var weekDay = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday",     "Friday", "Saturday"]
    document.getElementById('ok').innerHTML = "you were born at " +    weekDay[t.getDay()];
}
```

```html
<p> day :</p> <input type="text" id="day"/>
<p> month :</p> <input type="text" id="month"/>
<p> year :</p> <input type="text" id="year"/><br/>

<input type="button" value="Check "onclick="dayBirthDay()"/>

<p id="ok"></p>
```

I guess, you are getting the wrong results because of `setMonth` issue.

Note that `setMonth` takes integer **from 0 to 11**. So, January will be 0 and December will be 11.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code works

```js
function dayBirthDay(){
    var t = new Date();
    var day = document.getElementById('day').value;
    var month = document.getElementById('month').value;
    var year = document.getElementById('year').value
    t.setDate(day);
    t.setMonth(month);
    t.setYear(year);
 
    var weekDay = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday",     "Friday", "Saturday"]
    document.getElementById('ok').innerHTML = "you were born at " +    weekDay[t.getDay()];
}
```

```html
<p> day :</p> <input type="text" id="day"/>
<p> month :</p> <input type="text" id="month"/>
<p> year :</p> <input type="text" id="year"/><br/>

<input type="button" value="Check "onclick="dayBirthDay()"/>

<p id="ok"></p>
```